# How to create a category filter for a portfolio site?

Tags: craft3, categories, filter

I want to create a category filter similar to this website http://www.mypoorbrain.com/ (just a random website i found with the desired effect). Basically I want the categories to be displayed somewhere (All | Design | Web | Illustration) with the projects below. When a category is clicked, the projects shuffle to display just the projects with that category (not going to a new page).

I've looked through other category questions on here, and can't seem to find exactly how to do it (although I'm still pretty new to Craft, so I might not know what to look for with this).

Here is the code I have for the category loop (the filter)

Note: I have all of the categories I want (except for "All", not sure how to handle that) in the category group "Projects".

```
{# Create a category query with the 'group' parameter #}
{% set myCategoryQuery = craft.categories()
    .group('projects') %}

{# Fetch the categories #}
{% set categories = myCategoryQuery.all() %}

<div class="categories-wrapper">
   {# Display the navigation #}
   {% nav category in categories %}
      <a href="{{ category.url }}"><h3>{{ category.title }}</h3></a>
   {% endnav %}
</div>
```

And here is my current code for the project loop:

```
{% set projects = craft.entries.section('projects').all() %}
{% for entry in projects %}
<div class="project-thumbnail-wrapper bg-darkBlue">
   <a href="{{ entry.getUrl() }}">
      {% set projectImg = entry.featuredImage.one() %}
       <img src="{{ projectImg.getUrl() }}" class="thumbnail">
       <div class="overlay bg-orange"> 
       </div>
       <h3 class="project-title">{{ entry.title }}</h3>
       <p class="project-category"> Category </p>
   </a>
</div>
{%endfor%}
```

So how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site you linked to is using [Isotope](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/) to achieve this effect. Isotope is simply a JavaScript filtering library - it's all front-end so really this has nothing to do with Craft, unless you want to load entries dynamically via AJAX.

(Most Isotope implementations I've seen simply load everything and then hide/show the relevant ones when clicking on filters... It depends how many items you have as to whether it's worth loading them in dynamically, but it's a lot simpler to load everything in one go).

Comment: Good to know! I think that will work. I found another question/answer [link] (https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/30637/filter-entries-with-ajax) that helps with this too.